# New JQuery 1.5 breaks good old image lightbox... why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

Currently a (bought) JavaScript lightbox code works on my website that does work perfectly, only on older jQuery libraries like 1.3.2 and 1.4.3,  **but not on newer builds like 1.5**

> The problem on the new jQuery libraries is, that upon clicking a thumbnail the screen first goes into the dark mode but the lightbox never shows up, somewhere during that process it stops. This happens only if I load the new jQuery libraries, which I do prefer to use since all rest of my site works faster it seems with the newer builds.

**Any hints Where I should be looking for / where to find Jquery differences?**
Your ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: You could always switch to one of the bazillion available lightboxen that work with the new version

Comment: Because not everything was made forward-compatible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 73 - "SWFObject is not defined"

**Edit:**
http://blog.jquery.com/2010/11/11/jquery-1-4-4-release-notes/

*BACKWARDS-INCOMPATIBLE CHANGES IN JQUERY 1.4.4
The .width() and .height() methods no longer return 0 when inspecting an element hidden using ‘display: none’. To determine if an element is hidden, always use .is(‘:hidden’).*

Your script is full of `height() == 0` or `width() == 0` or Maths calculations with width() or height().
My best recommendation is to stick with jQuery 1.4.3 or rewrite the plugin \o/

Comment: I don't know if it'll fix your issue but a JavaScript error is never good. Could you switch your website to jQuery 1.5 so we can see the bug ?

Comment: hehe yes I was back from a party but too soon to sleep for a developer :D

Comment: Could you give me an URL where I can see the bug?

Comment: add a `$lightbox.show();` after the line 225 `function() {`, before `loadContent(currIndex);` :)

Comment: @LekisS, thanks so much for your help, your answer, and your nightowl-intelligence-sharing-through-the-otherwise-lonely-night :)